# Create dynamic entity from nested classes to bind Devexpress net core Data Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, devexpress, devextreme

I have a data transfer object like this :

```
public class PerformanceCostDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long WorkId { get; set; }
    public string WorkTitle { get; set; } //For example: Work1
    public List<UserCostDto> UserCosts { get; set; }
} 
public class UserCostDto 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserFullName { get; set; } //For example: Smith, john, ...
    public long TotalCost { get; set; } //For example: 1250, 545, ...
}
```

Now, I filled this DTO with complicated queries in Linq. But How can I select records to bind Devexpress net core Data Grid like this table with EF Core:

```
WorkTitle    Smith    John    ...
---------    -----    ----    
  Work1      1250     545
```

Comment: You need DevExpress PivotGrid.  It will generate needed query automatically.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks, But how can I access UserCostDto in PerformanceCostDto?

Comment: You need flattened result - merge UserCostDto into PerformanceCostDto.  Define right columns, DataSource's LINQ query, then Pivot grid will run all needed queries to show grouped data.

Answer (score 0):

For the future : As @SvyatoslavDanyliv Said:

I flattened result (Merge UserCostDto into PerformanceCostDto) Then Pivot Grid will run all needed queries to show grouped data.